# Is there a way to get letters in alphabetical order with Emmet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Using `.card{$}*2` gives `<div class="card">1</div>` and `<div class="card">2</div>` But, can we get a and b, or a through z?

I asked that to ChatGPT, and it offered `div{a-z}*26`, `div{a-z}`, `div{$a-$z}*26` but none of them works.